# Visula force page dropdown in excel sheet

Tags: excel, salesforce, apex

I want to show the dropdown created in vf page in excel sheet.Precisely as the dropdown is working in vf page should also created in Excel sheet.This process should be done when vf page is hit an excel sheet is downloaded.

Comment: Please, show one input, one expected output and what did you try... This is not a free code service...

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego I tried this:
https://datatables.net/examples/api/form.html
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

But i get dropdown values as a list in  a column but not the dropdown in excel

Comment: In Excel, this values are introduce through Data Validation so, you will get just the data as it is, and if you want to introduce this dropdown list, then you should create a validation data. It can be created before any export... Google for Data Validation by list. It is easy and I don't have room in the comments to explain. Anyhow, if you can not fix it, just replay. And again, please, show your input, show or explain your expected output and show what did you try.

Comment: Hi @DavidGarcíaBodego no source for data validation in apex or jquery

Comment: In the sample you send... you have a dropdown list on Office with {Edimburg, London, New York, San Francisco, Tokio}, just place that list in your sheet and place a Data Validation against the location where you place this list.

Comment: Hi @DavidGarcíaBodego i dont want to do it in excel i want to handle it beforehand i.e before exporting to excel sheet